# openpyxl read out excel and save into database

Tags: python, django, database, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to read out an excel sheet and save it into my database. This is my excel table:
[image]

My code where I am trying to get the data and save it into an data array looks like this (workbook was loaded before with load_workbook):

```
def getExampleData(workbook):
    sheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name('ExampleData')
    titleCell = sheet.cell('D1')
    assert titleCell.value = u'Overview'
    startRow = (2, 1)
    endRow = (6, 1) #this is the first empty row and I have it hardcodened 
                     to this time but it needs to be dynamically found 
                     in the future
    data['ExData'] = {}
    for i in range(startRow, endRow):
        exData = {}
        exData['Name'] = sheet.cell(row=I, column=1).value
        exData['Param1'] = sheet.cell(row=I, column=2).value
        exData['Param2'] = sheet.cell(row=I, column=3).value
        exData['Param3'] = sheet.cell(row=I, column=4).value
        data['ExData'| = exData
return data['ExData']
```

and then I want it to load it into my database table named ExampleDB (the whole project is made with Django so I am loading the ExampleDB just with an import) like this:

```
def saveExampleData():
xData = data['ExData']
ex = ExampleDB.objects.filter(name = xData['Name'], param1 = xData['Param1'],
               param2 = xData['Param2'], param3 = xData['Param3])
ex.save()
```

I just want to say that I KNOW that this functions don't work but I think they show what I want to do. Maybe someone can help me to understand how this works.

I am thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, here is a solution, using [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) and [`sqlalchemy`](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

db = create_engine('sqlite:///stocks.db')
df = pd.read_excel('excelfile.xlsx')
df.to_sql('required_table', db, if_exists='append')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't want to change using Django and openpyxl. And this solution does not work for my situation. The excel sheet I am getting has other tables in it. This is because I need to loop through the rows to find the first empty row and send the var endRow. :)